# Function that is straight and starts oscillating from a certain point.

Tags: functions

I know that functions of the form x*sinx will oscillate increasingly. How would I get a function like x*sinx, but it travels in a straight line until, say x=10, then starts oscillating increasingly from there? I want this to be a function that can be expressed as y=f(x), which is not defined piecewise.

Comment: You may want to state you're not considering piecewise functions.

Comment: right. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one
$$f(x) = \left[ \frac{x}{10}  \right]\sin(x),$$
where $[x]$ is $x$ rounded down to the nearest integer (the floor function). It is kinda gimmicky. The function will be equal to zero for $x\in [0,10)$ and then start to oscilate increasing its amplitude every time $x$ increases by 10.

you could also use the Heaviside step function but you would probably consider that cheating.

EDIT: we could make the function continuous in a trivial way:
$$f(x) = \left[ \frac{x}{10}  \right]\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{10}\right),$$
for some $n \in \Bbb N$.